# Java IDE with GlassFish

Tags: ide, glassfish

Please recommend some JAVA IDEs comes with GlassFish server.

I have tried both Eclipse and Netbeans, both are not working consistently, I am looking for an IDE to support GlassFish by default without any stressful confgurations.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans 7.3.1 should work out-of-the-box. Are you downloading the Java EE distirbution that includes GlassFish?